# Selecting shapes within a range. Strange seemingly random result?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to select shapes within a range, but the result of the code isn't quite what I expected. It's randomly selecting more shapes than it is supposed to (which are not within the range).

```
Public Sub ShapeSelection()
Dim Sh As Shape
Dim selectedOne As Boolean
On Error Resume Next

With ActiveSheet
   For Each Sh In .Shapes
       If Not Application.Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range(Selection.Address)) Is Nothing Then
          If selectedOne = False Then
              Sh.Select
              selectedOne = True
           Else
              Sh.Select (False)
           End If
       End If
    Next Sh
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` like this will hide any errors you have.  Remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. there is in fact something wrong with the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strange behavior is caused by "Selection.Address"

Within your loop, when the first shape is found, you change current selection from range C3 let's say, to the first shape

The next time through the loop it's trying to compare (intersect) the address of the TopLeftCell to the address of a shape object: the shape object itself doesn't have an address (its TopLeftCell has one)

But you went about it the long way: you don't need to use intersect. The code bellow works as you'd expect:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShapeSelection()

    Dim Sh As Shape
    Dim sRng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set sRng = Selection
        For Each Sh In .Shapes
            If Sh.TopLeftCell.Address = sRng.Address Then
                Sh.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Sh
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**: I just noticed your previous question: [How to select multiple shapes based on range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212480/how-to-select-multiple-shapes-based-on-range)

The intersection is needed to accomplish that requirement, but you still need to keep a reference to the selected cells:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShapeSelection()

    Dim Sh As Shape
    Dim sRng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
            Set sRng = Selection
            If sRng.CountLarge = 1 Then
                For Each Sh In .Shapes
                    Sh.Select False
                Next Sh
            Else
                For Each Sh In .Shapes
                    If Not Application.Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range(sRng.Address)) Is Nothing Then
                        Sh.Select False
                    End If
                Next Sh
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted: I'd appreciate an opportunity to learn from my mistakes

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but you get an upvote from me! I think you are correct. ... Ok, Just confirmed, you are correct! This was I'm not used to shapes in vba and I'm a bit tired already. Not saving the range was a silly mistake. I'm still learning, (not formally, but simply from doing it). In this case I just made a brainstorming a sheet and now it's very useful to select multiple shapes (or even all of them) without having to select them one by one (with Ctrl + LClick). Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and I'm glad you found it helpful!